# Extra pagination pages being wrongly generated

Tags: pagination, paginate-links, permalinks

Our site has correctly functioning pagination such as http://youronthepodium.co.uk/category/uncategorized/page/2/. However, a load of extra pages are being generated with the following parameters

- ?page_number_0=1
- ?page_number_0=2
- ?page_number_0=3
- etc.

This happens to a lot of pages (not just archive pages), which results in a craaaazy amount of pages when crawled by bots such as google's.

We don't know where these are coming from, and they don't serve any function other than risk our SEO and mess up any site-crawler reports.

A Screaming Frog crawl returns over 4,000 pages, because of these parameters being appended to so many pages. (Even http://youronthepodium.co.uk/category/uncategorized/page/2/?page_number_0=3 !)

Could anyone help determine where these extra parameters are coming from?

Many thanks.

Comment: The query argument `page_number_0` is not part of WordPress core, so it's probably coming from a plugin, or perhaps your theme. You could try searching the source files for that string or just `page_number` to try and find the culprit, or go through the process of disabling plugins and switching to a core theme.

Comment: Many thanks, this was great advice and good practice, with only a couple of complications. (See below answer)

Comment: Happy to help! Glad you solved it, and thanks for reporting back with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out these erroneous links were generated by [Facebook Feed WD plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wd-facebook-feed/).

Searching the code for phrases such as `page_number_0` didn't turn up any results, as the code in question was imported from outside the server, and switching to the default theme gave a red herring because it hid the widget and fixed the issue, leading me to believe it was a theme issue instead of a plugin one.